# ASP.NET jQuery - Bound Controls

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview, autocomplete

I want to use jQuery with a GridView which contains textboxes, but I'm stuck on how to get event listeners registered for every textbox on the selected row. I was thinking I could do something with a StingBuilder in the Unload event of the GridView but I can't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a CSS class to each TextBox and use a jQuery selector to find them?

```
<asp:GridView runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-CssClass="someclass" DataField="xxx" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then you should be able to do...

```
$().ready(function() {
  $(".someclass").function() {
   //do something interesting
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many textboxes (which it sounds like you do) better to delegate the event to some parent container rather than attach lots of events (event delegation)
Start reading [here](http://www.danwebb.net/2008/2/8/event-delegation-made-easy-in-jquery)